# R. Apriori. Preprocess data to know the name of the attributes in the rules

Tags: r, rules, apriori

I am using the dataset "adult".
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult
I have retrieved frequent rules using apriori and sorted them by lift.

```
library(arules)
trans = read.transactions("adult.data", format = "basket", sep = ",", rm.duplicates = TRUE)
rules <- apriori(trans)
rules.lift <- sort(rules, decreasing = TRUE, by="lift")
```

When I execute

```
  inspect(head(rules.lift,100))
```

I obtain the following:

```
    lhs                 rhs               support confidence     lift
  1   { 13,                                                            
      Male,                                                          
      United-States} => { Bachelors}    0.1024507  0.9976077 6.066125
  2   { 0,                                                             
       13,                                                            
       Male,                                                          
       United-States} => { Bachelors}    0.1024507  0.9976077 6.066125
```

ETC

For example, in the rule:

```
 { 0,                                                             
   13,                                                            
   Male,                                                          
   United-States} => { Bachelors}
```

How can I know which attribute that `0` and that `13` are? I have looked at the description of the data set and to the data itself so I guess that `13` is the education-num and `0` is the capital-loss but sometimes two or more attributes can have the same ranges so I would not know how to distinguish them.

```
>class(rules.lift)
[1] "rules"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"
```

I've read here: [How could we know the ColumnName /attribute of items generated in Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399068/how-could-we-know-the-columnname-attribute-of-items-generated-in-rules) that the problem is I haven't preprocessed the data. So, how can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would help if you made your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What is the R code you used to generate `rules.lift`. What is `class(rules.lift)`?

Comment: I've added the code to obtain rules.lift and its class. Thank you! :)

Comment: If you look at the "adult.data" raw input there are no category labels for the "columns" of data. And when you read the data as transactions with format="basket", it doesn't expect the data to be in a tabular format. It treats each column value as a flag ignoring column positions. If you use the build in `Adult` data set that comes with the `rules` package, you can see they've changed the variables to include "headers": `data("Adult"); rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(support = 0.4)); rules.sub <- subset(rules, subset = rhs %pin% "sex" & lift > 1.3); inspect(sort(rules.sub)[1:3])`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand what is going on :) How can I add those headers and consider the position of the columns? Again, thank you so much, you helped me to understand what I was doing! :)